# Content overwritten on top of another when formula is applied to excel cell using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am getting an issue of content being overwritten on top of another i.e old value and new values overlap after applying formula. And this issue only occurs Microsoft Excel 2010. How do I handle this?

I have tried refreshing the formulas for entire workbook using formula evaluator but still the issue persists.

```
private String applyTtlAvlFormula(final int colId, final int hrsColId)
    {   
        String ttlFormulaString = "";
        for( int i = ttlAvlContentRow; i < tableHeadStartRow+1; i++) {
            String colName1 = CellReference.convertNumToColString(hrsColId);
            String colName2 = CellReference.convertNumToColString(colId);
            ttlFormulaString += "("+colName1+String.valueOf(i)+ "*$"+colName2 +"$"+String.valueOf(i)+")";
            if (i != tableHeadStartRow){
               ttlFormulaString += "+"; 
            }
        }

        return ttlFormulaString;

    }
cell.setCellFormula(applyTtlAvlFormula(j,hrsCol));
```

Following are pre and post shots of the issue.

[image: pre-snap]
[image: post-snap]

From the images it can be seen that 40 and 32 gets overlapped after applying the formula. How can this issue be resolved.

Comment: Nobody will be able reproducing this issue without having [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the issue with the output that I am getting before and after applying the formulas